# Time Offsetting in pandas using multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas Dataframes:

One a float called sdtarray (representing seconds):

```
    z1  z2  z3  ...
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   2.6 3.4 63.0
2   NaN NaN NaN
3   0.1 1.1 60.7
4   4.7 5.2 64.9
5   0.1 0.6 61.1
...
[33945 rows x 95 columns]
```

and another a formatted date (thenewtime):

```
0    2014-09-01 05:22:00
1    2014-09-01 05:38:00
2    2014-09-01 06:08:00
3    2014-09-01 06:27:00
4    2014-09-01 06:37:00
5    2014-09-01 06:57:00
...
Name: thenewtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What is the best way to offset each row in the float DataFrame (sdtarray) by the corresponding date (same row index but thenewtime DataFrame) - ending up with a DataFrame of dates?

example output would be:

```
    z4                  z5                  z6              …
0   NaN                 NaN                 NaN 
1   01/09/2014 05:38:02 01/09/2014 05:38:03 01/09/2014 05:39:03 
2   NaN                 NaN                 NaN 
3   01/09/2014 06:27:00 01/09/2014 06:27:01 01/09/2014 06:28:00 
4   01/09/2014 06:37:04 01/09/2014 06:37:05 01/09/2014 06:38:04 
5   01/09/2014 06:57:00 01/09/2014 06:57:00 01/09/2014 06:58:01
…
```

I am using pandas 0.13.1 which I know doesn't help things but am stuck with this as it has to be compatible with numpy 1.7.1 due to ArcGIS requirements.

I managed to get the right output using itertuples on each row (and using a timedelta but it's incredibly slow for large data (34k rows by 100 cols) and there must be a more efficient way not reliant on examining each rol / column in a loop.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: Question does the following work: `date.values + sdtarray.apply(lambda x: pd.TimedeltaIndex(x, unit='s'))`? this assumes your date df is called `date` and that `sdtarray` is your first df, this works in pandas `0.17.0`

Comment: Unfortunately not. AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'TimedeltaIndex'", u'occurred at index z1'). I assume TimedeltaIndex was introduced in later versions of pandas (after 0.15?)

Comment: possibly, that's a shame as this would be how I would do this, otherwise try this: `def func(x):
    return pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(x['z1'], unit='s'), pd.Timedelta(x['z2'], unit='s'), pd.Timedelta(x['z3'], unit='s')])
#sdtarray.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
date.values + sdtarray.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)`

Comment: When you have NaN values, are they always all or None? That is, can you mix NaN values and seconds in the same row?

Comment: The same applies for Timedelta- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Timedelta'                   


Alexander - NaN values should remain as NaN. I don't want to add the seconds in those instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I convert the dataframe of seconds (`df1`) into `datetime.timedelta` objects after first checking that they are not `NaN`s.  I then add these values to the dates in `df2`.

Tested under Pandas 0.13.1.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'z1': [None, 2.6, None, 0.1, 4.7, 0.1], 
                    'z2': [None, 3.4, None, 1.1, 5.2, 0.6], 
                    'z3': [None, 63, None, 60.7, 64.9, 61.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['2014-09-01 05:22', '2014-09-01 05:38', '2014-09-01 06:08', 
                                 '2014-09-01 06:27', '2014-09-01 06:37', '2014-09-01 06:57']})
df2['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Datetime)

result = df1.applymap(lambda x: dt.timedelta(seconds=x) if not np.isnan(x) else None) 
         + np.tile(df2.values, (1, df1.shape[1]))

>>> pd.DataFrame(result)
                          z1                         z2                         z3
0                        NaT                        NaT                        NaT
1 2014-09-01 05:38:02.600000 2014-09-01 05:38:03.400000        2014-09-01 05:39:03
2                        NaT                        NaT                        NaT
3 2014-09-01 06:27:00.100000 2014-09-01 06:27:01.100000 2014-09-01 06:28:00.700000
4 2014-09-01 06:37:04.700000 2014-09-01 06:37:05.200000 2014-09-01 06:38:04.900000
5 2014-09-01 06:57:00.100000 2014-09-01 06:57:00.600000 2014-09-01 06:58:01.100000
```

Comment: Works a treat and exactly as needed. A good way to get round the bug issue if working with older versions of pandas. Solving my problem this way instead of using itertuples and iterating through each row reduced the time it took to run for the full data from over 30mins to 1min! Thank-you so much

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

For a fully vectorized solution, convert the seconds to timedelta objects by

```
seconds_td = (1e9*seconds.fillna(0)).astype('timedelta64')
```

Multiplying by `1e9` converts to nanoseconds. We fill the null values as the type conversion will fail otherwise.

The you can do

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    thenewtime.values + seconds_td.values.T
).T.where(df1.notnull().values)
```

Notice here the calculation is on the underlying arrays. This is because the broadcasting fails when working with the Pandas objects due to some bug or other. 
The column names will be lost but you can easily put them back in:

```
result.columns = seconds.columns
```

It's not the cleanest but it should be orders of magnitude faster than using `.applymap`. You can do it more cleanly in later version of Pandas. Here is some benchmarking with 100K rows:

```
seconds = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000, 10))
seconds.loc[np.arange(0, 100000, 3)] = np.nan

%%timeit 
seconds_td = (1e9*seconds.fillna(0)).astype('timedelta64')
thenewtime = pd.date_range('20151120', freq='H', periods=100000)

result = pd.DataFrame(
    thenewtime.values + seconds_td.values.T
).T.where(seconds.notnull().values)
1 loops, best of 3: 247 ms per loop

%timeit seconds_td = seconds.applymap(lambda x: dt.timedelta(seconds=x) if not np.isnan(x) else None)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.54 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks - it gives me an error: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer. So I'd need to convert but this has given me a good way forward. Thanks. I'll try this later

Comment: The code runs but for some reason (the bug maybe) it adds the seconds as hours and hence the output is wrong (unlike the above solution). For example the output for z1, 1 (col, row) for this method is 01/09/2014 08:42
(05:38 + 2.6 hours) instead of the required 05:38:02.6

Comment: That's very odd. This worked for me in 0.13.1. Ok I've edited again. I don't think the different units are handled well in this version but working in nanoseconds seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

One method which is not as neat as the answer in my comments which would be simpler and easier in 0.17.0:

```
In [81]:
def func(x):
    z1 = pd.NaT
    z2 = pd.NaT
    z3 = pd.NaT
    if pd.notnull(x['z1']):
        z1 = dt.timedelta(seconds =x['z1'])
    if pd.notnull(x['z2']):
        z2 = dt.timedelta(seconds =x['z2'])
    if pd.notnull(x['z3']):
        z3 = dt.timedelta(seconds =x['z3'])
    return pd.Series([z1,z2,z3])
date.values + sdtarray.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1) 

Out[81]:
                        0                       1                       2
0                     NaT                     NaT                     NaT
1 2014-09-01 05:38:02.600 2014-09-01 05:38:03.400 2014-09-01 05:39:03.000
2                     NaT                     NaT                     NaT
3 2014-09-01 06:27:00.100 2014-09-01 06:27:01.100 2014-09-01 06:28:00.700
4 2014-09-01 06:37:04.700 2014-09-01 06:37:05.200 2014-09-01 06:38:04.900
5 2014-09-01 06:57:00.100 2014-09-01 06:57:00.600 2014-09-01 06:58:01.100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it column by column with dateutils package. 
if df is seconds dataframe and d2 is dates dataframe

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

df2.columns = ['Date']
combo = df2.combine_first(df)
combo.fillna(0).apply(lambda x: x['Date'] +  relativedelta(seconds=x['z1']), axis=1)
```